# Find files for which multiple variations on that filename exist together in the same directory

Tags: shell-script, sed, find, filenames, performance

I want to list the files for which there exists, in a given directory, ALL of these files:

- `<filename>.wed`
- `<filename>.tis`
- `<filename>.are`
- `<filename>LM.bmp`

I am currently doing it with `find` and `sed`. It works but it is inelegant and slow!

```
find . -iname "*.wed" -exec echo {} \; | sed s/.wed$// $1 | sed s/..// $1 | while read in; do find . -name "$in.are"; done | sed s/.are$// $1 | sed s/..// $1 | while read in; do find . -name "$in.tis"; done | sed s/.tis$// $1 | sed s/..// $1 | while read in; do find . -name "$in*.bmp"; done
```

Basically I chain a `find`, two `sed` and a `while read` for each extension I want to filter on.

It takes >35s for barely 30K files! How can I improve it?

#### Example

If in the directory there are files called `AR0505.are`, `AR0505.tis`, `AR0505.wed` and `AR0505LM.bmp`, then the script would print "AR0505".

If one or more of these files was missing, then the script wouldn't print it.

Comment: `for file in "*.wed"; do ls "$file" "${file%.wed}.tis" "${file%.wed}.are" "${file%.wed}LM.bmp"; done`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the major bottleneck is the number of processes you spawn. Here is a simple script which lists and filters your directory in one pass:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %files;
my $dir;
my @extensions = ("\.tis","\.are","LM\.bmp","\.wed");

opendir($dir, ".") || die "Error opening dir\n";
while (my $file = readdir($dir)) {
    foreach my $ext (@extensions) {
        if ($file =~ /^(.*)$ext$/sm) {
            $files{$1} += 1;
        }
    }
}
closedir($dir);

foreach my $file (keys %files) {
    if ($files{$file} == scalar(@extensions)) {
        print "$file\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the leading `m/^(.*)` in the match when checking if something ends with something?

Comment: Wow awesome this is so fast, less than a second in the same directory!

Comment: I don't know Perl, would there be a way to count the number of extensions so the `4` is not hardcoded?

Comment: @MasterScrat Sure, here you go.

Comment: @thrig I catch the name of the file this way (in variable `$1`). The `^` is probably redundant but I put it there for "self-documentation".

Answer (score 6):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for all file names that exist with each of the target extensions. If so, you could do:

```
( shopt -s nullglob; 
  for i in *.wed; do 
    set --  "${i//.wed}"{.tis,.are,LM.bmp}*; 
    [[ $# -eq 3 ]] && printf '%s\n'  "${i//.wed}"; 
done )
```

#### Explanation

- `shopt -s nullglob` : this is a bash-specific option that makes globs expand to a null string instead of themselves if no matching files are found. The `( )` are there just to ensure that the option is only set for this command and won't affect the parent shell.
- `for i in *.wed; do ...; done` : iterate over all files or directories in the current directory whose name ends with `.wed`, saving each as `$i`.
- `"${i//.wed}"` : the file name without the `.wed` extension.
- `set --  "${i//.wed}"{.tis,.are,LM.bmp}*` : the braces will expand to `foo.tis`, `foo.are` etc, and the `*` is a trick to make bash attempt to match them as globs. This means it will only work if the actual file name exists.
- `[[ $# -eq 3 ]] && printf '%s\n' "${i//.wed}"` : if there are exactly 3 files in `$@`, so 3 in addition to the original `.wed` one, print the filename without the extension.

---

If you want to print all 4 file names, including the extension, just change the `printf '%s\n' "${i//.wed}"` to `printf '%s\n' "$i"`.

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -type d  -exec sh -c '
   h=$1; cd "$h" || exit
   set -- /dev/nul[l] [f]oobar.{wed,tis,are} [f]oobarLM.bmp; shift
   case $# in 4 ) for arg; do printf "%s/%s\n" "$h" "$arg"; done ;; esac
' {} {} \;
```

N.B.: Here we don't look at anything else but these 4 files & in the specific case and only when `ALL 4` are found, then it displays them, even if other `foobar.XXX` files existed in the same directory. Coz the OP was not very clear about that.

Comment: No that's not it. I tried to clarify the question...

Comment: @MasterScrat: I have provided a Bash-based & a pure-Perl solutions to your question. You may want to check those.

Answer (score 1):

## Bash

We set up a `for` loop with a `glob` expression `*LM.bm[p]`, so that we can disambiguate the scenario of file with name ending in `p` actually existing versus not. This is a bare-bones variety of `shopt nullglob`. If we see a name end in `p` => the shell was able to expand that glob, meaning, such a file existed. OTOH, if we see a name end in `[p]` => the shell was `NOT` able to expand the `glob *LM.bm[p]` meaning, there was no file with that name.

Next step is we clip the trailing 6 chars (L M . b m p) from the filename which we now know exists. Using the remaining part of the filename, we set up 3 positional parameters corresponding to the 3 extensions `.wed .are .tis`.

The key is that even if one of the extensions is left unexpanded, then it's name would show up with it's last character included in a `[ ]`. => All 3 files are not all present. => skip this . And the else clause => all 3 files are present + 1 (*LM.bmp) is already present due to our prior check. Hence we see all 4 files and => fit for printing.

```
for i in *LM.bm[p]; do
   case $i in
      *[p] )
         f=${i%??????}
         set -- "$f".we[d] "$f".ar[e] "$f".ti[s]
         savIFS=$IFS
            IFS=/
            case "$*/" in
               *"]/"* ) : ;;
               *      ) printf '%s\n' "$f" ;;
            esac
         IFS=$savIFS
   esac
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -le '
   while ( <*LM.bmp> ) {
      (my $f = $_) =~ s|LM\.bmp$||;
      print $f if 3 == grep { -e $f . $_ } qw/.tis .are .wed/;
   }
'
```